# Push failed to Heroku - Python Django

Tags: django, heroku

I was trying to deploy my django app on heroku, I did not create a virtual environment, and this is my first time doing it. When I tried to push to heroku I got error after installing all packages -:

```
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/tmp/build_b0d1f9a6/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
       main()
     File "/tmp/build_b0d1f9a6/manage.py", line 18, in main
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
       utility.execute()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
       collected = self.collect()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
       handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 338, in copy_file
       if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 248, in delete_file
       if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 318, in exists
       return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 38, in path
       raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
 !   Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
     See traceback above for details.
     You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
     Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
       $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !   Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !   Push failed
```

I cannot understand what to do, I am new to heroku, git.

[image]

This is how my directory looks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't added static_root in your settings...

let me help you,
make sure you have added this in your projects urls.py file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

& In your settings.py you have to add this, so collect static will load your static files for this domain.
for ex.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"
```

then try to run collect static command

if you want to learn more about this static files you can see this documents:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT

Comment: So basically I need to upload my static file on any cloud storage, and give a link to that ?

Comment: no! you have to add these in your settings.py file then run the command: python manage.py collectstatic. Then it will work.  i think the problem is that, heroku is not able to detect your static files so we have to give link of those static files. by doing static_root u will tell the heroku where to find those static files. you can learn about static files from the documentation. i have provided the links take a look at them